# Не срабатывает keyup() при вставке значения в input чере контекстное меню "Вставить" , disabled НЕ удаляется. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма (код ниже). При вставке **валидного** значения в поле с **помощью Ctrl+V все работает** - кнопка submit становиться доступной. **Если вставлять** **невалидное**, то **кнопка недоступна**... То есть все работает правильно.

Однако если вставлять валидное значение **через контекстное меню "Вставить"** **или в Firefox через подсказки** (*ранее вводимые заначения в input*), то кнопка не становится активной.

Подскажите как исправить?

Заранее, благодарю!

```js
var errorEmail2 = true, errorName2 = true, checkBox2 = true;

var ticketAuthor = $("#ticket-author"); // Автор
var ticketAuthorEmail = $("#ticket-author-email"); // Email
var tiketCheckBox = $("#pre_poll_choice");


var minNameVal = 2; // Минимальное количество символов в поле Имя
var maxNameVal = 50; // Максиимальное количество символов в поле Имя
var nameMinMax = [minNameVal,maxNameVal];
var patternName = "[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9_. -]{" + nameMinMax +"}";

var patternEmail = /[a-z\d-]+([\.\_]?[a-z\d-]+)+@[a-zа-я\d-]+(\.[a-zа-я]{2,6})/g;


/* Проверка поля Имя */
ticketAuthor.keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();  
  if(value == ""){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("Поле Имя пустое");
 errorName2 = true;
  }else if (value != value.match(patternName)){
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
 $("#name_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#name_valid").html("От 2 до 50 символов. Только буквы, цифры и символы: <b>. – _</b>"); 
    errorName2 = true; 
  }else{  
   if (value.length >= minNameVal){
   $("#name_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#name_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorName2 = false;
 }  
  }  
});


/* Проверяем корректность E-mail */
ticketAuthorEmail.keyup(function(){
var value = $(this).val().trim();

if(value == ""){   
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Поле Email нужно заполнить");  
 $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
 errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else if(value != value.match(patternEmail)) {
 $("#email_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#email_valid").html("Введите реальный Email");
    $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
    errorEmail2 = true; 
  } 
  else{
   $("#email_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#email_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");
   errorEmail2 = false;
  }
});

// Проверка чекбокса
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      $(this).val("on");
   $("#checkbox_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#checkbox_valid").html(""); 
   $(this).removeClass("err-textbox").addClass("ok-textbox");
   $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
   $("#submit_valid").html("");      
   checkBox2 = false;    
    }else{
  $(this).val("off");
  $("#checkbox_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
  $("#checkbox_valid").html("Вы не дали согласие на обработку персональных данных");  
  $(this).removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");
  checkBox2 = true;   
 }    
});


// Если все поля валидны, делаем кнопку доступной
$(document).keyup("input", function(){
if(!(errorEmail2 || errorName2)){
$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled"); 
}else{
$("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
}   

});


// В результате клика по кнопке отправить если ошибок заполнения нет то форма отправляется иначе получаем сообщение об ошибке
$("#submit").click(function (){   

  var chBox = tiketCheckBox.val().trim();

// проверка на наличие ошибок
if (errorEmail2 || errorName2 || checkBox2){

  if(chBox != "on"){
 $("#checkbox_valid").css("display"," inline-block");
 $("#checkbox_valid").html("Вы не дали согласие на обработку персональных данных");
  tiketCheckBox.removeClass("ok-textbox").addClass("err-textbox");    
  }  

$("#submit_valid").css("display"," block");
$("#submit_valid").html("Ошибки в полях!"); 
 
 // блокировка отправки формы
 return false;
 
  }else{
    $("#submit_valid").css("display"," none");
 $("#submit_valid").html("");
 console.log("Ошибок нет, форма отправляется!");
  }     
});
```

```css
label{display:none}


 textarea:focus,
 input:focus,
 button:focus 
 {outline:0!important;}

.err-textbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(255,0,0);   
}

.err-textbox:not(checked) + label::before{
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgb(255,0,0);   
}

.ok-textbox {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(124,245,124);   
}

#pagetitle_valid,#editor_valid,#name_valid,#email_valid,#checkbox_valid,#submit_valid{
display:none;
/* display: inline-block; */
padding: 1px 5px 5px;
color: red;
font-size: 12px;
}

.form-group b {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #f5dfdf;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

input#submit:disabled,input#submit[disabled]:hover,
button#pre_submit:disabled,button#pre_submit[disabled]:hover 
{ 
 background: #cecaca!important;
 color: #999!important;
 box-shadow: none!important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
 -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
 border: 2px solid #ccc!important;
 cursor: text
}
```

```html
<!-- форма -->
<form action="" method="get" id="ticketForm" class="well create">
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="name_valid"></span> 
 <label for="ticket-author">Имя</label><span class="error"></span>     
 <input type="text" name="author_vo" id="ticket-author" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваше имя" maxlength="50" value="" required> 
</div>
 
<div class="form-group">
 <span id="email_valid"></span>  
 <label for="ticket-author-email">Ваш Email</label><span class="error"></span>      
 <input type="email" name="email_author_vo" id="ticket-author-email" class="form-control input__no-radius" placeholder="Ваш Email" maxlength="50" value="">   
</div>

   <span id="checkbox_valid"></span>
   <div style="float:left;"> 
    <input class="form-control radio_poll" type="checkbox" id="pre_poll_choice" name="pre_poll_choice" value="off">
    <label for="pre_poll_choice" style="margin-top: 10px;">Даю согласие на обработку <a href="#"  target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">персональных данных</a></label>
   </div>
   

<div class="form-actions row">
 <div class="move-right"><span id="submit_valid"></span>
  <input type="submit" class="more buttons blue" name="draft" id="submit" value="Отправить вопрос" disabled="disabled">    
 </div>
</div>  

</form><!-- / форма -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Используйте on('change') для отслеживания.
Для примера попробуйте "поиграть" с
`ticketAuthorEmail.on('change',function(){console.log(1)});`

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE, не совсем понял, можете привести пример - изменеть код в своем ответе

Comment: Почему вы вставляете такую маленькую часть вашего проекта? Надо **весь** проект вставлять. Тогда будет более ясно всё. Все смогут почитать **весь** ваш проект, ознакомиться с ним, написать к нему тесты, прогнать их и решить **вашу** проблему. Ведь своих ни у кого нет. По теме. Я, конечно, не читал код, но недавно решал ту же проблему. Помимо вызова валидации по нажатии клавиш, еще добавил в код валидацию по событию 'change'. Это решило мою проблему. Это было сделано очень грубо, скорее всего есть варианты поизящнее, но время - деньги. Поэтому я скопировал кусок кода и поменял click на change.