# setInterval / setTimeout / clearInterval - Валидация поля - Нужна помощь по поводу ОСТАНОВКИ ТАЙМЕРА после "Вставки" значения через контекстное меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Событие keyup** - пока печатается всё с клавиатуры - всё хорошо. Пользователь вводит текст, обработчик проверяет на правильность и если что-то неправиьлно - меняет стиль поля, показывая что есть ошибка. Даже когда посетитель вставляет содержимое из буфера обмена комбинациями клавиш (Ctrl+V или Shift+Insert), обработчик нормально реагирует. Когда же вставляем из контекстного меню, то обработчик не работает.

Сделал на **setInterval** / **setTimeout** / **clearInterval** **два варианта** кода, но есть проблема  в обоих!

**1-вариант** работает как надо, если вставить через контекстное меню валидное значение в поле, то сразу же меняется стиль на валидный, **ОДНАКО** таймер как до, так и после продолжает считать.

**2-вариант** после вставки значения в поле через контекстное меню и даже с помощью (Ctrl+V или Shift+Insert) **нужно снять фокус (кликнуть ВНЕ поля)**. Счетчик при смене классов считает один раз.

**Задумка, чтобы до вставки и после таймер выполнялся один раз, а клас менялся сразу после вставки валидного значения или не менялся, если значение невалидно. То есть как в первом варианте, только таймер при смене класса выполнялся один раз.**

Помогите подправить!

Заранее, благодарю!

Ниже **два варианта** кода.

**1 вариант:**

```js
$(function(){
    var isCorrectName=function() {
        if (/^[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]/.test(this.value)) {
            $(this).removeClass('text-error-input');
   console.log("Класс text-error-input - УДАЛЕН - поле ВАЛИДНО"); // для тестирования 
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('text-error-input');
   console.log("Класс text-error-input - УСТАНОВЛЕН - поле НЕВАЛИДНО"); // для тестирования
        }
    }
    var changeFieldNameTimeout=null;



    $("#changeFieldName").change(function() {
        
            changeFieldNameTimeout=setInterval(function() {
                isCorrectName.call(document.getElementById('changeFieldName'));
            }, 500);            
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.text-error-input {
    border: 1px red solid !important;
    background: #FFB647 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="changeFieldName" name="changeFieldName" value="name1" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2 вариант**

```js
$(function(){
    var isCorrectName=function() {
        if (/^[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]/.test(this.value)) {
            $(this).removeClass('text-error-input');
   console.log("Класс text-error-input - УДАЛЕН - поле ВАЛИДНО"); // для тестирования 
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('text-error-input');
   console.log("Класс text-error-input - УСТАНОВЛЕН - поле НЕВАЛИДНО"); // для тестирования
        }
    }
    var changeFieldNameTimeout=null;



    $("#changeFieldName").change(function() {
        
            changeFieldNameTimeout=setInterval(function() {
                isCorrectName.call(document.getElementById('changeFieldName'));
            }, 500);
        
             setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(changeFieldNameTimeout);     
    }, 500);
        
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.text-error-input {
    border: 1px red solid !important;
    background: #FFB647 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="changeFieldName" name="changeFieldName" value="name1" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может вот это поможет:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input')
        .forEach(i => i.onkeyup = i.onpaste = i.onchange = () => validate(i));

function validate(field) {
  setTimeout(() => field.classList.toggle('invalid', /[0-9]/.test(field.value)))
}
```

```css
.invalid{
  background-color:wheat;
}
```

```html
<input><br><br><input><br><br><input>
```

PS: в этом примере невалидное значение - то которое содержит цифру

Comment: Благодарю, но дело в том, что помимо классов, необходимо еще добавлять или удалять `disabled` из `submit`, выводить надписи об ошибках и др., кроме того этот вариант не кроссбраузерный... [вот изначальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977661/Не-срабатывает-keyup-при-вставке-значения-в-input-чере-контекстное-меню-Встав) ... а сейчас просто придумал вариант с таймером, но не все удалось реализовать